# Funcion gotoxy en GCC,, consegui un ejemplo de como crearla pero no entiendo el codigo

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Buscando como ubicar el cursor en un determinado cuadrante de la pantalla para imprimir un texto halle esta función. Puedo memorizarmela ya que es corta pero en si no entiendo varias de cosas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gotoxy( int x, int y )
{
    printf( "\033[%d;%df", x, y );

} // Fin de la funcion gotoxy

int main(void)
{
    system( "clear" );
    gotoxy( 3, 8 );
    printf( "Hola\n" );

    return 0;

} // Fin de la funcion main
```

- En la instruccion `printf( "\033[%d;%df", x, y )`:
- ¿Que significa `"\033"`?
- ¿Después de `\033` hay un corchete abierto `"["`, para que se usa, que representa y por que no hay otro corchete de cierre?
- ¿El parámetro de variable `%df` cuando se usa?

Comment: ¿Estas compilando para linux o para windows?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes controlar cómo se ve la consola mediante [secuencias de escape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI) (resaltado mío):

> Los códigos de escape ANSI se utilizan para dar formato a la salida de una terminal de texto y se basan en un estándar ANSI, ANSI X3.64 (también denominado ECMA-48). Cuando se intenta representar un código de escape la terminal lo intercepta y actúa en función a ese código, cambiando el color o moviendo el cursor. Las posibilidades de las secuencias de escape son muy variadas y se utilizaban para dar formato y cambiar el aspecto de lo que se va a mostrar por la terminal.
>
> En MS-DOS era necesario instalar ANSI. SYS que permitía actuar ante esos códigos. Todos **los códigos de escape comienzan por los caracteres ESC (carácter ASCII número 27 decimal, 1B en hexadecimal) seguido del carácter [.**

El `\033` es el número 33<sub>8</sub>, que equivale a 27<sub>10</sub> o 1B<sub>16</sub>, por lo tanto es el carácter de escape, después va el corchete y a continuación los parámetros de escape que en este caso parece que pretenden posicionar el cursor en las coordenadas facilitadas.

El `%df` no es más que `%d` ([imprimir un número](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)) seguido de una `f`.